# Register level programming of GMA 950 hardware

Tags: graphics, driver, intel, cpu-registers

I'm trying to write a basic driver for the GMA 950 hardware.  I've been looking for a datasheet or some programming guide but cannot find anything.  I've also looked at the Linux and FreeBSD source but they are quite large and will take time to understand.  The GMA 950 is associated with an Intel 945 Express chipset.  Does anyone know of good documentation that I can write hardware register level code to for the 950 and/or 945?

Thanks,
FM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Intel® 945G/945GZ/945GC/945P/945PL Express Chipset Family](https://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/datasheet/307502.pdf) datasheet should be everything you need (at least, even according to the Chipset Development Kit manual)

GMA registers are on page 173.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what your looking for, as it looks like it is just for i965, but the [Intel Linux Graphics Documentation](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/documentation.html) might help.

Comment: Excellent!  Perhaps the 965 is a superset of the 945?  I'll do some poking around with the registers defined in this document and see what I find.